# how to add a column in a table with a name that is stored in a temporary variable

Tags: oracle, loops, plsql, alter-table, temporary

I want to add a column in a table every time the loop is run. I created a temporary variable which would take a different name for each iteration in the loop. now I want to add a column in my table with same name. I tried something like this, part of code is shown in oracle sql developer:

```
DECLARE V_COUNT VARCHAR (10) := ZIP_COD
BEGIN
ALTER TABLE ABCD 
ADD V_COUNT varchar(10);

update ABCD b
set b.V_COUNT = (select d.ZIP_cod
from ORA_DMSTORE d
where b.id_dmstore = d.id_dmstore);
END;
```

this is showing the error " Usually a PL/SQL compilation error."
i don't know how to get rid of it. please help

Comment: What database product are you using?

Comment: I am doing it on oracle database

Comment: Why would you want to do this? It sounds like a horrible model. You'll have to use dynamic SQL to do this, and anytime you need to query the values. Why not have a separate table to hold the values; or just join to `ora_dmstore` since you seem to already have the `id` value to join with? You can have a view to do that if your aim is hide the 'complexity', maybe.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can't do `ALTER TABLE ..` in PL/SQL, you have to use `dbms_sql` or `execute immediate`:

And column names can't start with numbers, so you need some kind of prefix, `n` in my example.

So one possible solution would be:

```
DECLARE 
 V_COUNT VARCHAR (10) := ZIP_COD;
BEGIN
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE ABCD ADD (n'||V_COUNT||' varchar(10))';

 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '
 update ABCD b 
   set b.n'||V_COUNT||' = (select d.ZIP_cod
                             from ORA_DMSTORE d
                            where b.id_dmstore = d.id_dmstore)
 ';
END;
/
```

Comment: What if the value to be added in the new column is stored in a temporary variable? will i use it as 

update ABCD b set b.n'||V_COUNT||' = ||temp_variable||

Comment: more or less, you're missing a quote: `set b.n'||V_COUNT||' = '||temp_variable` and take care of type casts of `temp_variable` (i.e. date to char or similar. Better to use bind variables in this case: `set b.n'||V_COUNT|| = :temp_variable' using temp_variable`